# SSH-1 key length

Tags: ssh, key

What is the maximum size in bits of one SSH-1 key? 4096?

I found some docs where this value is listed and others without limit

Comment: I don't think there's a mathematical limit to the length of an RSA key pair.  However, there are both practical limits as well as implementation limits.  SSH1 relied on `openssl` for key generation, so the implementation limit on keys would be found in `openssl` ...  It's quite possible to generate an 8192 bit key using current SSH2 implementations by `ssh-keygen -b 8192 -m PEM -f long_rsa.key` and inspecting the key using `openssl rsa -in long_rsa.key -text` ... `SSH1 and 2 differ more in session key protocol than key size limitations...

Comment: I think this may offer some clarity. https://serverfault.com/questions/129137/what-is-the-longest-password-for-ssh